# How to handle "extra" skill points?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, skills

I'm building a GMPC character who's backstory involves learning forging from a smith father and learning violin (perform [string instruments]) from his mother. I don't want to waste points where I don't need to, but I also don't want the skill ranks to reference sentiment to his dead mom. how do I handle this in character building?

By the way he is a warblade/duskblade gestalt (though I'm ignoring specific class skills for point limitations)

Basically, how do I have the ranks in the skill without ending up having it backfire because of it being useless?

I put the 3.5 and pathfinder tags because I'm using expansions from 3.5. (unless pathfinder has everything 3.5 has where then I'd like to see where)

Comment: Are you asking how to avoid placing skill points in a skill you think is useless, or how to get a skill without placing skill points in it, or what?

Comment: I basically am asking how I can get it without feeling like I'm wasting the skill points

Comment: So, the title isn't talking about extra skill points, it's talking about "extra" skills?

Comment: Also, is this D&D 3.5e, or Pathfinder? The difference will be important for answers.

Comment: Also, you keep writing class/class. What... do you mean? Are they gestalt characters? Are those choices you're pondering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You are the GM – do what you think is fair, and then *make it fair* by doing the same for the players

I habitually give away ranks in Craft, Perform, or Profession for backstories, typically 4 in 3.5 or just the 1 in Pathfinder. Making those three in particular into “always class skills” is also a common thing I do (I do make exception for Perform in some cases).

Perform and Profession, in particular, are almost *purely* fluff abilities, with little-to-no mechanical merit. Craft is somewhat better, but mundane crafting also takes absurd amounts of time, such that it is fairly rare to have happen after the game starts. Pathfinder expands the use of Craft a little bit, so you’ll have to consider that when you give out skill points, but it’s also *just one skill point*.

Anyway, this character sounds like he deserves a skill point (or 2-4 in 3.5) in Craft (Metalworking) and Perform (Stringed Instrument). So, do that, **and then look over your players’ character sheets and give them appropriate skill ranks too.** Either refund skill points, if they actually did spend skill points for “backstory taxes,” or give them the points they should have but didn’t pay the tax.

Because these are mostly-meaningless, it shouldn’t really matter if one person gets more or less than another; they don’t really do anything.

But restrict it to 1st-level skill ranks. This is for their backstory, the things they did growing up; if they want to keep up the practice and bring it to masterful or legendary levels, they should pay for that.

Comment: Is this incentive in 3.5 only on the first level, or do they get free skill points all the way up to 20? Or does it depend on the usage of the skill?

Comment: @ThomasJacobs Look at the last sentence of the answer maybe?

Comment: I don't care if I got the question closed. This answer almost everything, but is craft really useless?

Comment: @CataruMoore Without limitless time, for an adventurer, yes. It takes to long and produces too little to be worthwhile. While a few Craft skills are *interesting* (e.g. poisonmaking, wordsmithing), the vast majority are pointless in most campaigns. This could easily be its own question if you want more detail.

Comment: @CataruMoore Craft (weaponsmithing) and Craft (armorsmithing) are OK-ish, at least as part of a backstory – it’s easy to say you spent **seven years** in your backstory to craft your own *adamantine full-plate* in order to save 11,000 gp – but once game-time starts it’s unlikely you’ll actually finish anything significant.

Comment: @KRyan Unless it's a campaign with wide swathes of downtime, but yes, those are rarities in 3.PF.

Answer (score 2):

## If it doesn't *do* anything, it shouldn't *cost* anything

If a character can, for example, create very pretty but ultimately worthless tchotchkes because he learned how from his father or can play the violin very well but no one's interested in the weird style of playing he learned from his mother, neither of these minor character details need be reflected on the character's sheet. They're as useful as, for example, being able to belch the character's nation's anthem or the character's poop being the color of rainbows.<sup>1</sup> That's *just* detail—albeit *interesting* detail—, and the presence of such a detail among your GMPC might encourage your players likewise to consider appropriate useless, harmless details for their characters.

But if, for example, the tchotchkes were magical (e.g. they glow, animate, or speak) or the violin playing attracts creatures from other dimensions, then we're talking class levels, spells, magic items, psionics, superpowers, or whatever. That kind of ability *should* cost.

Not everything needs to be useful or dangerous. Some things can be just for fun.

As GM, monitor such details among your PCs carefully, though. Some folks'll try to monetize or weaponize *everything*.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Were it to *glow*, however, that'd be a thing.